# Traversing Contacts though Account object Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, relationships

I have a Visualforce page with a standard controller Account. I want to access a rich text field in a related Contact. Below is what I tried:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!Account.Contacts__r.rich_text_field}"  escape="false" />
```

However it is giving me the error below:

```
Invalid field Contacts__r for SObject Account
```

My understanding is since for 1 Account you can have many Contacts i.e. one to many relationship, and since I am at the Account level, I can use the 'Child Relationship Name' on the lookup field in Contact to traverse to the child object (Contact) and select the Contact field I need.

Is this wrong? I am unsure why I have this error.

Comment: @M guy, your thoughts are correct, and I will give you a tip. Lets imagine you have 2 related contacts to account. What then? Which rich text field will be displayed? from first ot second contact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is since for 1 Account you can have many Contacts
>   i.e. one to many relationship

This is the exact reason why you **can't** access child record from parent as they could be many and system doesn't know which one to select.

`Account.Contacts` returns a **list**(__r is for custom objects ) and you can't access any field from a list without going to a particular record.

Either you can iterate the child records or have query on child object querying parent fields in it.

Comment: I thought you use __r when you want to traverse relationships. When do you use/ do not use __r?

Comment: @Mguy  See my updated answer.

Comment: Does that mean for any lookup, you can use Object.relationship and it returns a list. From here you would index and select the fields required?

Comment: @Mguy Yes this is exactly what needs to be done.

Comment: Got it. Think I need a little more practice with relationships but thank you!